# SELECT dos últimos 365 dias (12 meses) em sql

Tags: sql

Bom dia! Estou a ter alguma dificuldade a fazer um `SELECT` que selecione os dados dos últimos 365 dias (12 meses).

O que quero que mostre é: nos últimos 12 meses tem de mostrar (por mês) um número (neste caso a soma dos `id` criados nesse mesmo mês).

Penso que o erro seja nesta parte do código:

> `BETWEEN now() AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)`

Mas não sei bem pois o ***Workbench*** não dá erros! Apenas não mostra nada!

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id, DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%m-%Y') AS data_mes
FROM ticket
WHERE ticket_state_id = 2 AND create_time BETWEEN now() AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)
GROUP BY MONTH(create_time);
```

Comment: Não coloque resolvido no titulo da pergunta, que não é a forma como o site funciona. Você indica se a questão foi resolvida aceitando uma resposta, clicando na marca verde ao lado da mesma

Comment: Agradeço a informação! Uma vez que ainda sou recente no site. Sendo assim eu só poderei aceitar a minha própria resposta daqui a 2 dias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muito obrigado a todos os que se disponibilizaram para me ajudar, mas felizmente já consegui resolver.

O código para resolver está aqui:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id, DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%m-%Y') AS data_mes
FROM ticket
WHERE ticket_state_id = 2 AND create_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) AND now()
GROUP BY MONTH(create_time)
ORDER BY create_time;
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: resultado do código acima]

Answer (score 2):

bom dia,

Valida se esta situação é o que pretendes

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id, DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%m-%Y') AS data_mes
FROM ticket
WHERE ticket_state_id = 2 AND 
    DATEDIFF(day,create_time ,GETDATE())<=365
GROUP BY MONTH(create_time);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Isso também funciona, mas não é o que quero! Felizmente já consegui resolver e publiquei a resposta correta a esta pergunta!
Mais uma vez obrigado pela disponibilidade! ;D